# Get the name an the description of a link category

Tags: categories, slug, link-category

I have a link category with the id `$id=23;` and the slug `$slug=friends;`. I managed to read all links from that category using `get_bookmarks($id)`.

Now I also want to use the name and the description ob the link category. How geht I get these values? I tried for example:

```
$cat = get_the_category($id);
$output .= "<p>Description: ".$cat[0]->category_description."</p>";
```

unfortunately this (and other things) did not work.

So how can I receive the name and the description ob the link category with the id=23? Is it also possible to recieve this via the slug of the link category? I tried `get_category_by_slug($slug)`, but this always gave an empty result,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

example:

```
<?php 
$link_id = 23;
$link_category = get_term_by('id',$link_id,'link_category'); 
var_dump($link_category);
?>
```